# How do I limit entries retrieved except those with a sticky lightswitch on the entry?

Tags: entries, lightswitch

I have a list of "meetings" as entries and I want to show only the last two ordered by meetingDate, and show any other meetings marked as sticky, without doubling up.

What I have so far is:

```
{% set stuck = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).sticky('1').order('meetingDate desc').find() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).order('meetingDate desc').limit(2).find() %}
{% set entries = entries|merge(stuck) %}
```

Now this works except that if an entry marked as Sticky is one of the first two, then it shows twice. I understand it is bad practice to try and manipulate data using Twig, and that rather I should aim on getting the right data out of the entries first up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to check to see if item is not in array before merging. The downside is that the entries will just be appended vs sorted by meetingDate.

```
{% set stuck = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).sticky('1').order('meetingDate desc').find() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).order('meetingDate desc').limit(2).find() %}

{% for stuckEntry in stuck %}
    {% if stuckEntry not in entries %}
        {% set entries = entries|merge([stuckEntry]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The other method is to grab the ids from the 2 queries and then merge them together, and perform a new query which can be sorted.

```
{% set stuckIds = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).sticky('1').ids() %}
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).limit(2).ids() %}

{% for id in stuckIds %}
    {% if id not in entryIds %}
        {% set entryIds = entryIds|merge([id]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.id(entryIds).order('meetingDate desc') %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that - but for some reason stuckEntry always gets added to the entries array, so it ends up there twice. i.e. {% if stuckEntry not in entries %} gets evaluated as true so it seems that the array items are somewhat different.

Comment: That's very strange... I've definitely used that technique in the past. Worst case, you can get the ids, then do another query just using the ids.

Comment: Yes, it is, and I can't troubleshoot why - I used your code snippet exactly (which was in effect the same as mine). Your idea of using the ids works, but seems like a complicated workaround. But I thank you for offering me a solution.

Comment: The ID approach is the way to go if you want your last items sorted into that array of sticky posts and not just appended to it, @Jack.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I ended up with, thanks @douglas-mcdonald and @carlcs

```
{% set stuck = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).sticky('1').order('meetingDate desc').find() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('meetings').relatedTo(subcategory).order('meetingDate desc').limit(2).find() %}
{% set idArray=[] %} 
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set idArray = idArray|merge([entry.id]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% for entry in stuck %}
    {% set idArray = idArray|merge([entry.id]) %}
{% endfor %}
{% set unique=[] %} 
{% for entry in idArray %}
    {% if entry not in unique %}
        {% set unique = unique|merge([entry]) %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
{% set publish=[] %}
{% for entry in unique %}
  {% set publishItem = craft.entries.id(entry).first() %}
  {% set publish = publish|merge([publishItem]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you are doing more work than needed. You can grab the ids using the `ids()` method, and then merge them if not already in array. Then grab all the entries properly sorted by meetingDate using the ids. See [updated answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9543/784).

Comment: Ah, right - thanks - I'm not that familiar with retrieving data - that is a lot simpler!